# Explaining how to measure on the real line

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory

If you were to explain to an undergrad statistics student with limited exposure to measure theory, how would you best explain having measure on real line?

For example, to make things more relatable to the student, I am thinking of giving an example of giving the real line a measure by specifying a CDF function F, which is just any monotone increasing function with values between 0 and 1.

Now as to defining a measure having such a function, we could try for any interval $I=(a,b)$, the measure simply being $F(b)-F(a)$. Knowing this, we recover the measure uniquely. How do we get this CDF? We can do this via a function called PDF, which we assume not to be discontinuous, positive, integrates to 1.

How would you explain better or more concisely with the student-eye-level lingo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the PDF rather than the CFD to start with. You may want to try presenting a rope that has variable linear density, explain how this relates to the mass of small lengths of rope, then use integration to get the mass of any length of rope. That will get you to the CDF, assuming the rope has finite length. By the time they have understood that you can introduce infinite-length ropes without problem.

Of course drawing the CDF (maybe as it relates tot the thickness of the rope) will help.